# Combine NodeJS Fibers + VM Sandbox

Tags: node.js, node-fibers, nodevm, node-vm2

I want to run some untrusted code in Node that might look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    green_led(1);
    sleep(500);
    green_led(0);
    sleep(500);
}
```

Using Fibers, I got the synchronous behaviour working as expected:

```
var Fiber = require('fibers');

function sleep(ms){
    var fiber = Fiber.current;
    setTimeout(function(){ fiber.run(); }, ms);
    Fiber.yield();
}
function green_led(active){
    //...
}
Fiber(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        green_led(1);
        sleep(500);
        green_led(0);
        sleep(500);
    }
}).run();
```

The difficulty is how to sandbox the code. Having to use Fibers makes it really complicated; I'm not really sure how to start. How might I get the above sandboxed with [vm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2)? For example, the following obviously won't work:

```
var code = "\
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){\
    green_led(1);\
    sleep(500);\
    green_led(0);\
    sleep(500);\
}\
";
function sleep(ms){
    var fiber = Fiber.current;
    setTimeout(function(){ fiber.run(); }, ms);
    Fiber.yield();
}
function green_led(active){
    //...
}
Fiber(function(){
    vm.run(code);
}).run();
```

(It won't work because `green_led` and `sleep` are not visible to the sandboxed code in the VM).

How should this be done? Either...

1. Perhaps everything should be run inside the VM, including Fibers and implementation of `green_led` etc?
2. Or would it be better to keep code run by the VM minimal, and instead somehow whitelist/proxy `green_led` and `sleep`? Not exactly easy on the gray matter, it's hard enough understanding how Fibers work in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite straight-forward.

```
var Fiber = require('fibers');

const {VM} = require('vm2');
const vm = new VM({
    sandbox: {
        green_led: green_led,
        sleep: sleep
    }
});

function sleep(ms){
    var fiber = Fiber.current;
    setTimeout(function(){ fiber.run(); }, ms);
    Fiber.yield();
}
function green_led(active){
    //...
}

vm.run(
    `Fiber(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            green_led(1);
            sleep(500);
            green_led(0);
            sleep(500);
        }
    }).run()`
);
```

The above approach passes in a reference to `Fiber` and the other functions `sleep` and `green_led` via the sandbox object. This could be done in other ways. For example, `sleep` and `green_led` could be defined within the string passed to `vm.run()`, and the vm could itself `include` `fibers` like so:

```
const {NodeVM} = require('vm2');
var vm = new NodeVM({
    require: {
        external: true,
    }
});
vm.run(
    `
    var Fiber = require("fibers");
    function sleep(ms){
        var fiber = Fiber.current;
        setTimeout(function(){ fiber.run(); }, ms);
        Fiber.yield();
    }
    function green_led(active){
        //...
    }
    Fiber(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            green_led(1);
            sleep(500);
            green_led(0);
            sleep(500);
        }
    }).run()`
);
```

As per [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2), notice the difference between `VM` and `NodeVM`. Out of the above two methods, only the first would be able to make use of the timeout feature. Also, the second method is not immune to `while (true) {}` etc.